# Console not finding Shells in CakePHP for windows

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I'm having trouble getting the cake console on winows (XAMPP) to see the demo shell

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\twitter\app\vendors\shells>dir


2011/03/31  21:11    <DIR>          .
2011/03/31  21:11    <DIR>          ..
2011/03/31  21:16               761 demo.php
2011/03/31  21:01    <DIR>          tasks
2011/03/31  21:01    <DIR>          templates
```

I have the demo.php shell in the shell directory.

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\twitter\app\vendors\shells>cake demo

Error: Class DemoShell could not be loaded.
```

But the cake console couldn't find it.

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\twitter\app\vendors\shells>cake


Welcome to CakePHP v1.3.7 Console
---------------------------------------------------------------
Current Paths:
 -app: shells
 -working: C:\xampp\htdocs\twitter\app\vendors\shells
 -root: C:\xampp\htdocs\twitter\app\vendors
 -core: C:\xampp\htdocs\twitter

Changing Paths:
your working path should be the same as your application path
to change your path use the '-app' param.
Example: -app relative/path/to/myapp or -app /absolute/path/to/myapp

Available Shells:
 acl [CORE]                              i18n [CORE]

 api [CORE]                              schema [CORE]

 bake [CORE]                             testsuite [CORE]

 console [CORE]

To run a command, type 'cake shell_name [args]'
To get help on a specific command, type 'cake shell_name help'


C:\xampp\htdocs\twitter\app\vendors\shells>
```

And it isn't recognised by the console itself. (note the core is reading from the correct directory).

It's probably some silly oversight but any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

You should call `cake [shell name]` from within the app folder: `C:\xampp\htdocs\twitter\app\>cake demo`.

Please let me know if it works.

Answer (score -1):

Read the error, it does not say 'file not found'  it says 'class not found' so it would seem  you have named the class incorrectly inside your demo.php shell

Error: Class DemoShell could not be loaded. that is a hint as to what it should be

Comment: The "could not be loaded" is always displayed even if the file is not found (I tried the same using random characters).